# Git merge part of changes from another branch

Tags: git, git-merge

To be brief, I have two branches, let's say `branchA` with commit `commit01` and `branchB` with commits `commit11`, `commit12`, .... `commit15`. What should I do if I want to patch changes from `commit13` to `commit15` onto `branchA` (i.e. `commit01`)?

That is, how to make it: `commit15 - commit13` merge to `commit01`

The merging base of two commits are too old, and I just want part of changes in `branchB`. Thanks.

Comment: You keep saying "merge" but that isn't what you mean, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have this history:

```
  11--12--13--14--15     <-- branchB
 /
X--01                    <-- branchA
```

It is obvious that commits `13`, `14`, `15` can live without `12` and `11`, otherwise, you would not have the desire to "merge" just the former without the latter.

In this case, I suggest to reorder `branchB` and merge the early part to `branchA`:

```
  13'--14'--15'--11'--12'     <-- branchB
 /           \
X--01---------M               <-- branchA
```

You can use `git rebase -i X branchB` to reorder `branchB`.